# How to maintain interlink between multiple enums in c#

Tags: c#, enums

I'm new to c#, in java we used to have interlinking for enums like below:

```
 public enum Module
{
    None(SubModule.None),
    Authentication(SubModule.Login),
    User(SubModule.User,SubModule.ForgotPassword,SubModule.ResetPassword)


    private SubModule subModule;

    public Module(SubModule... submodule)
    {

    }

 }
```

I want to interlink my Modules with submodules, I tried the same in C# its giving compilation error. Is there anyway to do the same in C#.

Comment: enums in C# are not classes like they are in Java so I don't think there is a way.

Comment: @SelmanGenç is right, enums in C# are sort of [syntatic sugar](http://www.dotnetjunkies.net/csharp/enum-working-with-enumerations/)please read the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx), it might help you..

Answer (score 1):

C# enums are much simpler types than Java enums - they cannot have constructors, methods, or member fields.  However, you can achieve similar functionality using a class with static instances that represent each "enumeration."

```
public sealed class Module
{
    public static Module None { get; } = new Module(SubModule.None);
    public static Module Authentication { get; } = new Module(SubModule.Login);
    public static Module User { get; } = new Module(SubModule.User, SubModule.ForgotPassword, SubModule.ResetPassword);

    private SubModule[] _subModules;
    private Module(params SubModule[] subModules)
    {
        _subModules = subModules;
    }
}
```

This class allows you to access the static `Module` instances using basically the same syntax as an enumeration, and the private constructor prevents new instances from being created.

Note that `SubModule` could be a true C# `enum` if that suits your needs, or it could also be a class with static properties for "enum" values.